# Check if array has value

Tags: arrays, postgresql

I'm running this simple check:

```
select * from mytable
where field_name = any(array['2']::_varchar);
```

field_name is `_varchar`so it's an array

but I'm getting this:
ERROR: operator does not exist: character varying[] = character varying

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: `where '2' = any(field_name)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`=ANY` unwraps it RHS and compares them *individually* to the LHS, so it would be the same thing as `field_name = '2'::varchar`.  You can't compare an array to a scalar like that.  You want an operator that doesn't unwrapped the argument but compares arrays to each other:

```
field_name @> array['2']::_varchar
```

or

```
field_name && array['2']::_varchar
```

Or you want to leave the literal as a scalar, and then unwrap the other side which is already an array so it too becomes a scalar:

```
'2' =ANY (field_name)
```